# Excel: Count duplicates only once, based on third criterion

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

So I got a excel sheet that lists (amongst other things) organizations and the year they were active in. Some organizations were active more than once a year. It looks like this:

> YEAR  --   ORGANIZATION
>
> 2015      --- Orga A
> 2015     ---  Orga A
> 2015   ---    Orga B
> 2014    ---   Orga C
> 2014 --- Orga C
> 2013    ---   Orga D
> 2013 --- Orga D

**I'm trying to figure out a formula that will give me the number of *unique* organizations active per year** (in the example: 2 in 2015, 1 in 2014, 1 in 2013).

What I've tried:
I created a new column in C, and entered this formula in each row:

```
=COUNTIF($B$2:B*X*,B*X*)=1
```

X = 2 (B2), in the first row, and than rises by 1 per row (e.g. B2, B3, B4) That will output whether it is the first time that the organization was active (as YES/NO).

With this I can then create a simple COUNTIF formula that will count the number an organization was active.
The problem is however that this refers to whether the organization was active **in all years** more than once, not per individual year.

Writing the above mentioned function for every year is not an option, as the sheet should be sort of "self-sustaining", as it is an on-going list that will need to accommodate future years.

I feel like this could be solved with an array formula and an IF function, but I'm unsure how... Any input would be hugely appreciated! (:

Comment: You could totally use a PIVOT TABLE!

Comment: How so? If I use the Pivot Table's count function I do not eliminate the duplicates.

Comment: Have you tried Remove Duplicates?

Comment: Nope, how could I use that specifically?

Answer (score 0):

I found it very strange that nobody answered to this...
Well, I'll try then.

Ok, if you're not fond of pivot tables I can suggest you a couple of solutions that doesn't make use of them.

**FIRST WAY**

The prerequisites are that you have the list of all possible organization names as well as a list of all the years you want to check for the number of unique organizations active.

[image: Example]

In the example I showed, I put your list in column A (range `A1:A7`), the list of possible organization names in the range `C2:C5` and the years from 2013 to 2015 in `D1` to `F1` cells.

Now that you have this you can obtain what you need to know following these steps:

1. in `D2` put `=IF(IFERROR(MATCH(CONCATENATE(D$1," --- ",$C2),$A$1:$A$7,0),0)>0,1,0)`
   then copy the formula until `F5`.
   This will create a grid of 0s and 1s with 1 meaning that organization was active in the reference year and 0 meaning it wasn't.
2. Then all you need to do is simply getting sums in row 6 from D to F (simply put `=SUM(D2:D5)` in `D6` and then copy formula until `F6`).

Otherwise, if you don't need or don't want the grid, you can use a CSE/array formula (can find some links to know more about them in [another of my answers](https://superuser.com/questions/1095549/how-to-count-the-number-of-cells-in-a-range-containig-a-specific-substring-in/1095550#1095550)).

In the example, in `D7` I wrote `=SUM(IF(IFERROR(MATCH(CONCATENATE(D$1," --- ",$C2:$C5),$A$1:$A$7,0),0)>0,1,0))` then pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> and copied the formula until `F7`.
*(Just note that steps 1. and 2. are not necessary at all to get the desired results in this case.)*

**SECOND WAY**

Finally, if you can't get a list of all organizations easily, assuming you can only compile the list of the years you are interested in checking for, a possible solution could be the following:

1. Select all your data range (in my example it's `A1:A7`) and go to "Data" set and select "Remove Duplicates".

[image: Excel Data Remove Duplicates]

In this example only 4 rows should remain and they will be unique combinations of `year --- organization name` ([an example of how Remove Duplicates work](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/remove-duplicates.html)) so now we can simply "count" the number of times a year appear in the remaining rows data range. The number of rows that will remain after removing duplicates isn't really important as we will assume the entire A column as data range.

2. So, after having removed duplicates, what is left to do is use the formula (for example in `D8` and then copying to `F8`) `=COUNTIF($A:$A,CONCATENATE(D$1," --- *"))`
   *(just note that asterisk in the formula is an Excel wildcard, can find some links to know more about them in [the same other answer I mentioned before](https://superuser.com/questions/1095549/how-to-count-the-number-of-cells-in-a-range-containig-a-specific-substring-in/1095550#1095550))*

and that's it.