# How to count the number of cells in a range containing a specific (sub)string with Excel/Calc?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, libreoffice-calc, countif

Using Excel/Calc I have the following situation:

- a range of cells containing values; assume it's `A1:B10`,
- and a string I want to look for; for example, assume it is contained in `C1`.

Now what I want to do is count how many cells in the range equal that string
**or contain it as a sub-string.**  How do I get that? 
(For example, assume that I want the result in `D1`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I answer myself as I do this at least once a year and I feel the need of having a place to look for quickly when I forget something, plus I think this could be useful for someone else too.

So, ok, I know of two ways to do that:

1. using conventional formula

   in `D1` put     `=COUNTIF(A1:B10,"*"&C1&"*")`

   Some notes (mostly) for newbies:

   - those "*" in the formula are [Excel wildcards](https://www.deskbright.com/excel/excel-wildcard/)
     (a [list of Excel functions that can use wildcards](http://www.exceluser.com/excel_help/functions/guide-to-excel-wildcards.htm))
   - those "&" are a way to concatenate text without using CONCATENATE (more on this [here](https://www.deskbright.com/excel/combine-text-in-excel/) or [here too](http://excelsemipro.com/2010/08/concatenate-function-or-ampersand-operator-in-excel/) )
2. using [CSE/array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-array-formula-e43e12e0-afc6-4a12-bc7f-48361075954d)

   `D1` should be    `{=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C1,A1:B10)),1,0))}`

   ([more about Excel array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7))